# Closed curve is homologous to zero in simply connected domains

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

If I am in a simply connected domain, are all the closed curves homologous to zero?

i feel that this is true because a simply connected domain has no holes so there cant be a point outside the domain with a curve looping around it. is this correct?

Comment: Isn't that the *definition* of "simply-connected"?

Comment: @MartinR i don't know.. is it?

Comment: Well, as far as I know, that is the general definition (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space). In the complex plane there are several equivalent characterizations (e.g. the complement is connected). Perhaps you can clarify which definition you use.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of simply connectedness is that all curves are homotopic to zero, not homologous to zero. But it is fairly easy to see that homotopic to zero implies homologous to zero, so the answer to your first question is "yes". The reverse, however, is false: there are examples of curves homologous to zero but not homotopic to zero (this follows essentially from the fact that $H_1$ is the abelianization of $\pi_1$, so for example the cycle $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is non-zero in $\pi_1$ and zero in $H_1$).